# python flask env variable import error app

Tags: python, docker, flask, environment-variables, migrate

I have one `Dockercontainer` with some functionality which worked fine. I duplicated it and made some changes and provide them both via `docker-compose`. It works fine but suddenly I startet one of the containers new and get following error:

```
ra-offerservice    | Usage: flask db migrate [OPTIONS]
ra-offerservice    | 
ra-offerservice    | Error: Could not import "code.app".
```

(docker-compose --verbose up)

```
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('2d5df6e050d58a205a1d059493d2e3e99c06dee5ab70c45a0110db4dd18eb9c2')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('2d5df6e050d58a205a1d059493d2e3e99c06dee5ab70c45a0110db4dd18eb9c2')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/2d5df6e050d58a205a1d059493d2e3e99c06dee5ab70c45a0110db4dd18eb9c2/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 30
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 2}
ra-offerservice exited with code 2
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/2d5df6e050d58a205a1d059493d2e3e99c06dee5ab70c45a0110db4dd18eb9c2/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
 'Args': ['-c', '/usr/local/bin/boot.sh'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['/bin/sh', '-c', '/usr/local/bin/boot.sh'],
            'Env': ['SERVICE_NAME=ra-offerservice',
```

Don't know why it doesn't find the `app.py` anymore. I make no changes and before it works.

.env File

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
DATABASE_URL='postgresql://offer:offer@offerdb:5432/offerdb'
```

boot.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -e
FLASK_APP=app.py

#FOR DATABASE init
#flask db init
#For DATABASE migration
flask db migrate -m "update"

# sync database to latest migration
flask db upgrade
exec gunicorn --log-level info --log-file=/gunicorn.log --workers 4 --name app -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --reload app:app &
envoy -c /etc/service-envoy.yaml --service-cluster service${SERVICE_NAME}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM envoyproxy/envoy:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q install -y \
    curl \
    software-properties-common \
    python-software-properties

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q install -y \
    python3.7 \
    python3-pip

RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.7
RUN python3.7 --version && pip3.7 --version
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3.7 install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3.7 install gunicorn
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code

ADD ./boot.sh /usr/local/bin/boot.sh
RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/boot.sh

ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/boot.sh
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
import config
from models.offer import OfferModel
from resources.offer import Offer, OfferList
from resources.offer_admin import ActivateOffer
from resources.test import TestKlasse
from db import db
from ma import ma

app = Flask(__name__)

############################
### LOAD CONFIGRUATION
############################
app.config.from_object(config.DevelopmentConfig)

db.init_app(app)
ma.init_app(app)

api = Api(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
jwt = JWTManager(app)

############################
### ADD REST API ENDPOINTS
############################
#USER Endpoints
api.add_resource(Test, '/api/v1/test/<int:page>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I have absolutely nooo clue what's going wrong.

Comment: You may need to explain more about what exactly you did when you "duplicated it and made some changes." What exactly did you duplicate, how did you change it,  and what did it look like before and after the changes?

Answer (score 0):

make sure exsit **init**.py
show file directory

Comment: hi! I had an __init__.py in the same directory as app.py. I deleted it and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had 2 faults.

I was missing the `ENV` before `FLASK_APP=app.py` in the `.env` file above
--> But I still got the ERROR

```
ra-offerservice    | Usage: flask db upgrade [OPTIONS]
ra-offerservice    | 
ra-offerservice    | Error: Could not import "code.app".
```

I had an `__init__.py` in the same folder as `app.py`.

```
ra-demandservice
|-- models
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- models.py
|-- resources
|   |-- resources.py
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- app.py
|-- boot.sh
|-- .env
`-- Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just moved all files to another directory and renamed my `file.py` to `app.py`. You could else change `ENV FLASK_APP=app.py` from dockerfile to `ENV FLASK_APP=file.py`